# Button to return the value of a variable string

Tags: c#, winforms

Can a button return the value of a variable?is it possible? I'm new in winform so...understand me. The final goal is to have a simple code with two buttons that if clicked  return  a msgbox with the value of a var.

```
private string button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string res = "PASS";
  MessageBox.Show(res);
  return res;
}

private string button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string res = "FAIL";
  MessageBox.Show(res);
  return res;

}
```

Comment: You are already doing it when you are passing `res` value to `MessageBox.Show(res)`

Comment: You could write: `private void DisplayMessage(string message)
{
  MessageBox.Show(message);
}` and then call this method in both button click function like: `DisplayMessage(res);`

Comment: Who is supposed to *consume* the value returned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a return value from a Button Click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651484/how-do-i-get-a-return-value-from-a-button-click-event)

Comment: oh hi again @DmitryBychenko,the returned value is going to be used by another app in wpf

Comment: If you mean "can event handlers return a value?" then the answer is no. The method signature has to be compatible with the delegate (e.g. `EventHandler`)

Comment: nope @SeM, i've to do another thing, it must be symple because the path of the exe of this program  will be eated by another program ,practically  PASS or FAIL depending on the choice will be stored inside a db sql and shown into a datagrid wpf

Comment: oooooh,@JonSkeet what do i have to do to make a symple btn that if clicked return a value pass or a  value fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `button3_Click` and alike are so-called *callback functions* which are called by *system* and that's why do not return any value (the system doesn't need it). Let's *extract a method*:

```
private string MyButtonClick(object sender) {
  string result = "";

  if (sender == button3) 
    result = "PASS"; //TODO: better read it from resources, not hadcoded
  else if (sender == button4) 
    result = "FAIL"; //TODO: better read it from resources, not hadcoded

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    MessageBox.Show(result); 

  return result;     
}
```

And then you can put:

```
// System callback function

// void: System callback function signature
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  MyButtonClick(sender);  
}

// void: System callback function signature
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  MyButtonClick(sender);  
}
```

Or

```
// custom code

string myClickMessage = MyButtonClick(button4);
```

Comment: you'll never disappoint me,that was a easy shot...thank you so much dmitry...again

Comment: only a little improovement th types of the buttons is void not string

Comment: @mad codroipo: sure, it should be `void`: `void button3_Click` and `void button4_Click`

Comment: the only remaining question is how could i pick up the result from another app and insert it into a db?

Comment: @mad codroipo: applications interaction (if "another app" is a different *exe file*) is a difficult procedure (say, both exe establish named pipe(s) and send data to it in order to interact). If "another app" is just *another form* of the *same* exe all you have to do is to modify `MyButtonClick` (e.g. write code to save the message into RDBMS)

Comment: nono is a completly different app,completly separated

Comment: @mad codroipo: in this case I suggest you should start from interprocess interaction - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication - when your apps can tak to each other you'll be able to change `MyButtonClick` adding `BroadCastToOtherApps(result);`

Comment: the fact is that the other app TDM is able to manipulate a db, from that app i can add items to the db sql,so i've added the path of the .exe of this app (ResultMaker) into the db now if i check ResultMaker from the datagrid of TDM i can run RM wich return a value(pass or fail) i need to add the chosen value ,from RM, to the tab sql of TDM. but i've to do this operation from TDM and not from RM.it's not easy to explain

Answer (score 0):

Click event handlers have strongly typed signature, i.e. the return type **must** be `void`, so you cannot return anything from them.

But, if you are working with windows Forms, you have class for your form, where you placed those event hadnlers. So what you can do is: define private variable:

```
pirvate string _res;
```

and then assign it value in your click event hadlers, eg.:

```
private string button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _res = "PASS";
  MessageBox.Show(_res);
}
```

Then in the code you could use this value as you want.

If you want to use it outside your class, define property:

```
public string Res
{
  get { return _res; }
}
```